# Fit an image in fixed size <td> with 100% width but height with scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a image whose height is more than its width (the ratio could be up to 10 times , and width also keeps changing)

I have made a fixed td with width and height.

I am trying to fit the image in that  however I want it to display 100% its width and the height to be scrollable. The aspect ratio of the image should not change on display.

Here is my relevant code.

```
<body onload="getResolution();">
function getResolution() {
var w40w = 0.40 * window.innerWidth ;
var w80h = 0.8 * window.innerHeight ;
document.getElementById('question_td_verb_p_rc').style.width = w40w+'px';
document.getElementById('question_td_verb_p_rc').style.height = w80h+'px';
document.getElementById('question_td_verb_p_rc').style.overflow = "auto";
}

<table class="questiontable" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="6" id="question_td_verb_p_rc" style="padding-left:5px;">
            <a href='1.png' target="_blank"><img src="1.png"></a></td>
        </tr>
```

CSS

```
table.questiontable
{
    width:80%;
}
```

I have tried many things but none have worked. I get the image displayed as fit into the td, or if I set width 100% and height auto, I get the image displayed fitting the width 100% but pulling the table very long down.

The table height is 80% the screen height. (displays properly)
The td in question is the first column of the table and its the whole column.
The second column of the table has 6 rows in it.

I do prefer a javascript solution over a CSS solution however any solution is highly appreciated.

I hope I am understandable, apologies for my poor grip on the English language.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table cell will expand to accommodate the content.

If you wrap the td element's content in a div which has height and width 100% the system will know how much space to give it as you have already set the height and width of its parent element.

If you also set overflow-y: auto there will be scrolling only if necessary.

```js
function getResolution() {
var w40w = 0.40 * window.innerWidth ;
var w80h = 0.8 * window.innerHeight ;
document.getElementById('question_td_verb_p_rc').style.width = w40w+'px';
document.getElementById('question_td_verb_p_rc').style.height = w80h+'px';
document.getElementById('question_td_verb_p_rc').style.overflow = "auto";
}
```

```css
table.questiontable
{
    width:80%;
}
```

```html
<body onload="getResolution();">

<table class="questiontable" border="1" style="table-layout: fixed;">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="6" id="question_td_verb_p_rc" style="padding-left:5px;">
            <div style="height:100%; width:100%; overflow-y:auto;"><a href='1.png' target="_blank""><img src="https://ahweb.org.uk/gear.jpg" style="height:auto;width:100%;"></a></div></td>
        </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Note: in using JS to calculate dimensions remember that this needs to be done on a resize also (a user turning their phone from landscape to portrait or altering the dimensions of the window on a desktop). You might find the CSS viewport units vw and vh useful.

Comment: I cant get this to work as expected, upon putting height 100% it tries to fit the image in the <td> scaling it down to fit the height. The scrollbar is not visible, Removing the Height 100%, I get the width 100% but the <td> is pulled down revealing the whole image at once without a scrollbar. Thanks for the <div> idea,  I will try to play with the height of the <td> and the <div> a bit more and update my findings. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, are you saying my snippet doesn’t work for you? It was fine for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: It didn't work as expected. I am using chrome and my image height is 10 times its width. Its completely fitting inside the <td>. I want its width 100% and its height scroll able.

Comment: Hmm, it’s working fine for me. Can you put your image onto imgur or post its url so I can try it.

Comment: Working Perfect ! http://192.243.101.163/index.html (It must be something with the existing containers, because when I made this test page removing all the extra stuff, then its working fine)